# Como multiplicar dos matrices

Tags: java

Tengo problemas con la multiplicación de dos matrices
Las dos matrices son cuadradas, o sea que tiene la misma cantidad de filas y columnas, al multiplicarlos, esto se guarda en una tercera matriz.

Ya intente algunas formas pero al final solo me realiza correctamente la primera columna:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multiplicacion_matrices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, filas, columnas;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("----------MULTIPLICACION DE MATRICES----------");

        System.out.print("Introduce el tamaño de los arreglos: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        filas=n;
        columnas=n;
        int matriz1[][] = new int [filas][columnas];
        int matriz2[][] = new int [filas][columnas];
        int resultado[][] = new int [filas][columnas];

        System.out.println("-----MATRIZ 1: -----");
        for(i=0; i<filas; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<columnas; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce un valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                matriz1[i][j] = x;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-----MATRIZ 2: -----");
        for(i=0; i<filas; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<columnas; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce un valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
                int y = sc.nextInt();
                matriz2[i][j] = y;
            }
        }

        //realiza la operacion
        for(i=0; i<filas; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<columnas; j++) {
                int z = matriz1[i][j]*matriz2[j][i];
                //despues ya no se que mas
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-----RESULTADO-----");
        for(i=0; i<filas; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<columnas; j++) {
                System.out.println("Valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]:"+resultado[i][j] + " \n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ibas bien encaminado, tan solo tenias que hacer la multiplicación de cada posición de las dos matrices y guardarla en la posición correspondiente de la matriz resultado:

```
//realiza la operacion
for(i = 0; i < filas; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
        resultado [i][j] = matriz1[i][j] * matriz2[i][j];
    }
}
```

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multiplicacion_matrices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, filas, columnas;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("----------MULTIPLICACION DE MATRICES----------");

        System.out.print("Introduce el tamaño de los arreglos: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        filas=n;
        columnas=n;
        int matriz1[][] = new int [filas][columnas];
        int matriz2[][] = new int [filas][columnas];
        int resultado[][] = new int [filas][columnas];

        System.out.println("-----MATRIZ 1: -----");
        for(i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for(j=0; j < columnas; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce un valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                matriz1[i][j] = x;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-----MATRIZ 2: -----");
        for(i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce un valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
                int y = sc.nextInt();
                matriz2[i][j] = y;
            }
        }

        //realiza la operacion
         for(i = 0; i < filas; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
                resultado [i][j] = matriz1[i][j] * matriz2[i][j];
            }
        }


        System.out.println("-----RESULTADO-----");
        for(i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                System.out.println("Valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: " + resultado[i][j] + " \n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Al leer el comentario de @pablo, busque que efectivamente mi ejemplo es incorrecto.

**Nueva propuesta:**

```
for(i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
     for(j = 0; j < matriz2[0].length; j++) {
         for (int k = 0; k < matriz1[0].length; k++) {
             resultado[i][j] += matriz1[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
         }
     }
 }
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multiplicacion_matrices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, filas, columnas;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("----------MULTIPLICACION DE MATRICES----------");

        System.out.print("Introduce el tamaño de los arreglos: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        filas=n;
        columnas=n;
        int matriz1[][] = new int [filas][columnas];
        int matriz2[][] = new int [filas][columnas];
        int resultado[][] = new int [filas][columnas];

        System.out.println("-----MATRIZ 1: -----");
        for(i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for(j=0; j < columnas; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce un valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                matriz1[i][j] = x;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-----MATRIZ 2: -----");
        for(i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce un valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
                int y = sc.nextInt();
                matriz2[i][j] = y;
            }
        }

        //realiza la operacion
         for(i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < matriz2[0].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < matriz1[0].length; k++) {
                    resultado[i][j] += matriz1[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("-----RESULTADO-----");
        for(i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                System.out.println("Valor en la posicion ["+i+"]["+j+"]: " + resultado[i][j] + " \n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
----------MULTIPLICACION DE MATRICES----------
Introduce el tamaño de los arreglos: 2
-----MATRIZ 1: -----
Introduce un valor en la posicion [0][0]: 2
Introduce un valor en la posicion [0][1]: 2
Introduce un valor en la posicion [1][0]: 2
Introduce un valor en la posicion [1][1]: 2
-----MATRIZ 2: -----
Introduce un valor en la posicion [0][0]: 2
Introduce un valor en la posicion [0][1]: 2
Introduce un valor en la posicion [1][0]: 2
Introduce un valor en la posicion [1][1]: 2
-----RESULTADO-----
Valor en la posicion [0][0]: 8     
Valor en la posicion [0][1]: 8     
Valor en la posicion [1][0]: 8     
Valor en la posicion [1][1]: 8
```

Te dejo un enlace donde explica muy bien la multiplicación entre matrices. [Multiplicación de matrices en Java](https://dcodingames.com/multiplicacion-matrices-java/)

Comment: La multiplicación de matrices no es así

Comment: Acabo de ver como se multiplican las matrices, tienes razón pablo, fallo mio

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente te falta asignar el valor del resultado que guardas en `z` a la matriz `resultado[i][j]`, quedando de la siguiente forma el bucle:

```
for( i = 0; i < filas; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < columnas; j++ )
        {
            int z = matriz1[i][j] * matriz2[j][i];
            resultado[i][j] = z;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Tras la puntualización aportada por @PabloLozano, esta sería la solución correcta:

```
for(i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j < matriz2[0].length; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < matriz1[0].length; k++) {
         resultado[i][j] += matriz1[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Sabes cómo se multiplican matrices?

Comment: @PabloLozano Tienes razón, hace falta recordar conceptos básicos, gracias por avisar.

Answer (score 0):

La complejidad en la multiplicación de matrices está en que para cada posición (i,j) debes multiplicar toda la fila i por la columna j y sumar cada par:

```
int[][] multiplicar(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    int filas = m1.length;
    int columnas = m2[0].length;
    int filasResultado = m1[0].length;
    int[][] resultado = new int[filas][columnas].length;

    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        int valor = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
           for(int k = 0; k < filasResultado; k++) {      
               valor += a[i][k] * b[k][j];      
           }
           resultado[i][j] = valor; 
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```